# SQL query comparison (join condition in ON clause or in WHERE clause)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, left-join

[SQL fiddle link for sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3902/24/13)

Basically my doubt is , is it same if we specify a condition in **ON** clause of **LEFT OUTER JOIN** or we specify condition in **WHERE**  clause with null check ?

**Table schema :**

```
Create table App(ID number , STATUS varchar2(10));
Create table App_Child(child_id number ,
                       STATUS varchar2(10),
                       ID number );
```

**Query 1**

```
SELECT a.ID AS appID, a.STATUS AS appSTATUS,
b.child_id AS acOWNID,b.STATUS AS acSTATUS, b.id AS acID
 FROM App  a LEFT OUTER JOIN App_Child b ON (a.id=b.id AND b.STATUS <> 'disabled')  WHERE a.ID = ?;
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT a.ID AS appID, a.STATUS AS appSTATUS,
b.child_id AS acOWNID,b.STATUS AS acSTATUS, b.id AS acID
 FROM App  a LEFT OUTER JOIN App_Child b ON (a.id=b.id)  WHERE a.ID = ? AND (b.STATUS IS NULL OR b.STATUS<>'disabled');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not not is the same neither in results and **readability**.

- When you write condition in `on` clause you include all rows from App.
- When you write condition in `where` clause you filter rows from result:

In your case an `App` with row related with a App_Child with b.STATUS='disabled' **will be filtered**

Here a sample:

```
INSERT INTO App VALUES(1,'active');

INSERT INTO App_Child VALUES(3,'disabled',1);

SELECT a.ID AS appID, a.STATUS AS appSTATUS,
b.child_id AS acOWNID,b.STATUS AS acSTATUS, b.id AS acID
 FROM App  a LEFT OUTER JOIN App_Child b 
      ON (a.id=b.id AND b.STATUS <> 'disabled')  
WHERE a.ID = 1;

--- has results ---

SELECT a.ID AS appID, a.STATUS AS appSTATUS,
b.child_id AS acOWNID,b.STATUS AS acSTATUS, b.id AS acID
 FROM App  a LEFT OUTER JOIN App_Child b ON (a.id=b.id)  
WHERE a.ID = 1 AND (b.STATUS IS NULL OR b.STATUS<>'disabled');

-- don't has results --
```